# Issue running rails console - fiddle gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Error trying to run `rails c` on a macOS 12.6.5; ruby 3.1.4; rails 6.1.7.3. If I downgrade the application to ruby 3.0.6 I no longer get this error.

```bash
[WARNING] Could not load command "rails/commands/console/console_command". Error: uninitialized constant Fiddle::PackInfo::TYPE_UCHAR

      TYPE_UCHAR  => ALIGN_CHAR,
      ^^^^^^^^^^
Did you mean?  Fiddle::TYPE_CHAR.
/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4/gems/fiddle-1.1.1/lib/fiddle/pack.rb:14:in `<module:PackInfo>'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading the fiddle gem from 1.1.1 to 1.1.0 seems to work.

- `gem uninstall fiddle -v 1.1.1`
- Explicitly add `gem 'fiddle', '1.1.0'` to your Gemfile
- run `bundle install`
- `rails c` should work

Another solution that worked was to upgrade the `listen` gem (from 3.2 to >= 3.8). This seemed to be the culprit and with this change the fiddle gem does not need to be downgraded.